# Ajax call returns same result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a jquery modal button, where I want to display information from my database.

I have a field in the database where I want everything to be identified by it is called "number"
The modal button is displayed in a table which is already being looped from a SQL query displaying all entries

```
while ($row = getarray($res)){

    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td> <? $row["state"] ?> </td>
    <td><? $row["number"] ?></td>
    <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="detailsmodal(<?
    $row["number"])">Description</button>
  </td>
  </tr>


<!-- Modal Button -->
<button type ="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="detailsmodal(<?= $row['number']; ?>)>Modal Button</button>
<!-- Code for modal -->
<?php
$number =$_POST["number"];
$number =(int)$number;
$modalsql = myquery($dbvariable,"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Number = '$number' ");
$result2 = myfunction_fetch_array($modalsql);
ob_start();

?>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="closeModal()" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"> <?= $result2['number']?></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p><strong>Field 1:</strong><?= $result2['number']?> </p>
    <p><strong>Field 2:</strong><?= $result2['field_2']?>  </p>
    <p><strong>Field 3</strong><?= $result2['field_3']?> </p>
    <p><strong>Field 4:</strong><?= $result2['field_4']?> </p>
    <p><strong>Field 5:</strong><?= $result2['field_5']?></p>
    <p><strong>Field 6:</strong><?= $result2['field_6']?> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div> 

<?php 
ob_get_clean();
?>

<!-- Script for the modal-->
<script>
    function detailsmodal(number){

        var data = {"number" : number};
        jQuery.ajax({
        url : "/page1/page2",
        method : "post",
        data : data,
        success: function(){
            jQuery("body").append(data);
            jQuery("#myModal").modal("toggle");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Ideally, the information should be changed based on the different items that are being clicked. but it is staying the same.

Comment: The ajax is the last portion of code i submitted. And no matter which button i click in my table i get the first entry it pulls from the db only

Comment: When you debug, where specifically does the problem happen?  What is the resulting client-side code being generated here?  In your browser's debugging tools when you examine the network requests, do the AJAX requests have the data you expect?  When debugging the JavaScript in those same tools, what is the value of `number` and is it what you expect it to be?  What is the PHP code which is being invoked by the AJAX request?  What is it returning as a response?  There is *a lot* of debugging you can do here.

Comment: The problem is in the first line of the code you posted. You're passing a "number" calculated in php with `$row['number'];` to the function `detailsmodal`. You're alwasy passing the same number so you'll always get the same result.

Comment: I edited my code, i have a variable that loops though the db results and creates the table dynamically. All entries have a different number.

Comment: In chrome when i inspect the modal button and click it and go into network->all then click form data, its only shows number:0

Comment: @jumpman8947: Your edit shows a typo in the code.  You open a PHP short tag `<?` (which may or may not even be enabled in your PHP config) which you never close.  And within that tag you don't actually output anything.  Did you miss the `=` for the output, as well as the closing tag?  You also still need to examine the resulting client-side code to see where that `0` value is coming from.  Is that what's being emitted to the page in the first place?  If so then none of that client-side code has any bearing on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use following code , there are so many typo mistakes you have in your code.

```
<?php while ($row = getarray($res)){ ?>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td> <? $row["state"] ?> </td>
            <td><? $row["number"] ?></td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="detailsmodal(<?=
              $row["number"]) ?>">Description</button>
            </td>
          </tr>


          <!-- Modal Button -->
          <button type ="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="detailsmodal(<?= $row['number']; ?>)">Modal Button</button>
          <!-- Code for modal -->
          <?php
          $number =$_POST["number"];
          $number =(int)$number;
          $modalsql = myquery($dbvariable,"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Number = '".$number."' ");
          $result2 = myfunction_fetch_array($modalsql);
          ob_start();

          ?>

          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" onclick="closeModal()" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title"> <?= $result2['number']?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p><strong>Field 1:</strong><?= $result2['number']?> </p>
                  <p><strong>Field 2:</strong><?= $result2['field_2']?>  </p>
                  <p><strong>Field 3</strong><?= $result2['field_3']?> </p>
                  <p><strong>Field 4:</strong><?= $result2['field_4']?> </p>
                  <p><strong>Field 5:</strong><?= $result2['field_5']?></p>
                  <p><strong>Field 6:</strong><?= $result2['field_6']?> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>

         <?php
         ob_get_clean();
         ?>

         <!-- Script for the modal-->
         <script>
          function detailsmodal(number){

            var data = {"number" : number};
            jQuery.ajax({
              url : "/page1/page2",
              method : "post",
              data : data,
              success: function(){
                jQuery("body").append(data);
                jQuery("#myModal").modal("toggle");
              },
              error: function(){
                alert("Something went wrong!");
              }
            });
          }
        </script>
```